# Will US PS4 work on 220V?

Tags: ps4, hardware

I bought a new [PS4 Batman bundle from Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VETEZ16) and I was wondering if it will work on 220V. I asked the support in Amazon and did some research and people say that it would work, however when I chatted with PS support agent she said that it may or may not work! And she said that US PS may not work in other regions because it was designed specifically for US region. I thought that PS4 is region free no?

I went to Game Stop and a rep there confirmed that it will work on 220V

Can someone please confirm if it will work or not on 220V?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While "officially" Sony says North American PlayStation 4 consoles only accept 120 V, the power supplies the console actually ships with do support 100-240V at 50 or 60 Hz. This is confirmed by an [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/150182/CUH-1001A+B01+240V+support) thread asking this same question:

> jrjessjuliet:  Ok guys this is the final answer and please take note!! All ps4 models irrespective of region or model number are dual voltage! It's a portable console so it can travel with you to any country from 110v to 240v since it has a voltage regulator build in. I'm living in Malaysia with 240v but I'm using an Amazon PS4 from US with a rated 120v without any issues!!!
>
> ...
>
> Joe: The ps4 120 V is dual voltage.. I took the risk; I plugged it in and it works . Don t worry guys ;)

You can safely verify this yourself by checking for this label underneath your PS4, near where the power cord attaches:

[image]

The above picture was taken from [iFixit's PlayStation 4 teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/PlayStation+4+Teardown/19493#s54781), which also states:

> The power supply is rated at an AC Input of 100-240 volts. This means you can take your game around the world with your trusty PS4 always at your side; just remember to bring your power socket adapters.

Comment: sir you just made my day, thanks alot, yes I did found the label it says 100~240V

Comment: when in doubt, always check that label. Seems very peculiar that Sony would deliberately say it was made for North America standard, and non compatible with elsewhere, if it can support 100V-240V, but with this sort of thing, that label is 1000% more reliable then the manufacturer. 

Remember, match the voltage, and meet or exceed the ampage. Same rule applies to "can I use this power pack on my console" and "which chargers work on my laptop".

Comment: @Timelord64 It's not too hard to understand what Sony is doing here. The North American price of a consoles is, after adjusting for currency, usually lower than the price the console in other markets. Sony apparently wants to discourage "grey market" imports of the North American consoles to other regions.

Comment: I'm more surprised to see Sony rely so heavily on the ignorance of their users. This is definitely one of those things that can be checked and assured *so easily*, but I find a lot of people simply don't realise how, or understand it enough to feel comfortable making that call. Telling the user a lie so they will buy in the more expensive market. tsk tsk.

Comment: @Timelord64 i was really disappointed when i contacted their tech support, she should 've given me a definite answer but instead she told me it may or may not work! I was like if you guys don't know then who does?

Comment: @Timelord64. Most of the time, the problem is that people don't have access to the PSU spec label until *after* they bought the unit, and googling for a picture showing a readable label can be next to impossible. So while it's easy to determine if it's safe to carry your console with you abroad, it's really hard to determine if importing one is safe or not. Luckily, there's iFixit.

Comment: @Timelord64 Sony rootkit.  They have long relied on the ignorance of the consumer base to generate revenue.

Comment: Where I live, misinforming the customer like that actually entitles them to a refund

Answer (score 2):

It works! I have a US PS4 that says 120 V 2.1 amp on its back. And I brought it to Iran one year where the ac input is 220v. So I was hesitant to plug it in. After reading more than 50 articles I found an ifix that showed if you open you ps you can see tht under the power source it says it's universal (100-220v). So I did that and it worked perfectly. Ever since I've been playing here with no problem. Trust me, it works without a problem.

Answer (score -2):

Yes your PS4 should work just fine under 220V.

In regards to the PS4 being region locked this is not true. You will be fine to use and play EU games while abroad. I believe it will not play EU DVDs however.